# Convert curl command to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to convert this curl command to JavaScript:

```bash
curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin \
  --data-urlencode Email=mail@example.com \
  --data-urlencode Passwd=******* \
  -d accountType=GOOGLE \
  -d source=Google-cURL-Example \
  -d service=lh2
```

I want convert this command to an `$.ajax()` function. My problem is that I don't know what I have to put in the `setHeader` function below for the options present in command curl.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin",
    type: "GET",

    success: function(data) { alert('hello!' + data); },
    error: function(html) { alert(html); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});


function setHeader(xhr) {
    // ?
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default `$.ajax()` will convert data to a query string, if not already a string, since data here is an object, change the data to a string and then set `processData: false`, so that it is not converted to query string.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin",
 beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); 
 },
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json',
 processData: false,
 data: '{"foo":"bar"}',
 success: function (data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
},
  error: function(){
   alert("Cannot get data");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `fetch()` instead of `$.ajax`, you can use [curlconverter.com/javascript/](https://curlconverter.com/javascript/) and it will convert your command to

```js
fetch('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        'accountType': 'GOOGLE',
        'source': 'Google-cURL-Example',
        'service': 'lh2'
    })
});
```